# put data to hashmap without overwrite

Tags: java

i want add values to hashmap get from DB.resulset has 2 row data.but its overwrite firstly added row values.

this is my code.

```
        Statement s1 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = s1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM garantee WHERE loanapplicationid ='" + applicationid + "'");
        ResultSetMetaData garanteeMetaData = rs1.getMetaData();
        int garanteeColumns = garanteeMetaData.getColumnCount();
        HashMap<String, String> garanteeFull = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while (rs1.next()) {
            int j = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < garanteeColumns; i++) {
                garanteeFull.put(garanteeMetaData.getColumnLabel(i) + j, rs1.getString(i));
                System.out.println(rs1.getString(i));
            }
            j++;
        }
```

i use int j to change key value.but its not work corectly.please help me.how to do that

**sorry for bad English

Comment: debug it.. most likely "garanteeMetaData.getColumnLabel(i) + j" will have same value on both of the runs..

Comment: `j` is always 1. The increment at the end is redundant. Do you mean to put `int j = 1;` outside the `while` loop?

Comment: That (Andy Turner's bug) would have been notice with a debugger or simply with a log message in the loop. Remember to debug your program first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the following line outside while loop as whenever it's coming to the loop the value of j is becoming 1 every time.

int j = 1;

So please try with following code replacing your one..

```
    Statement s1 = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1 = s1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM garantee WHERE loanapplicationid ='" + applicationid + "'");
    ResultSetMetaData garanteeMetaData = rs1.getMetaData();
    int garanteeColumns = garanteeMetaData.getColumnCount();
    HashMap<String, String> garanteeFull = new HashMap<String, String>();
    int j = 1;
    while (rs1.next()) {

        for (int i = 1; i < garanteeColumns; i++) {
            garanteeFull.put(garanteeMetaData.getColumnLabel(i) + j, rs1.getString(i));
            System.out.println(rs1.getString(i));
        }
        j++;
    }
```